# File saving location for Mac applications

Tags: c++, ios, macos, std

I am porting my iOS project to Mac

I am saviving few files, and on the iOS, I saved it inside the .app under Documents/, however, by MAC OSX the file doesnt get created

```
/Users/SMTH/Desktop/Development/SIO2 2/SIO2_SDK/tutorials/MyMacApp/macos/build/Debug/00_template.app/Contents/MacOS/../Documents/menustate.sav
```

using

```
std::ofstream file;
file.open(fpath.c_str(), std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
```

iam i doing smth. wrong. or is i not possible to save inside the Mac OSX app like to the iOS app (where to save then on the MAC?)

Edit : i also tryed other locations like 
`file.open("~/Documents/menustate.sav", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);` but still no file is created

**the only path which was savable, was the "./" -> "./menustate.sav", which saved it to somepath/00_template.app/Contents/Resources'** but why can it save to Resources, and nowhere else?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Basically you should not as in OSX Apps can be used by more than one user and so Apps are often stored as writable only by the installer and not by normal users.

The open call is I assume a call over the unix [open](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/open.2.html) function - If so look at the return value of file.open and see if it is -1. if so then look at the global variable errno so see why it failed. A decent C++ class wil have wrapped that up to give you the error in an exception thrown by open.

For MacOSX look at Apple's doc on [where to put application files](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFileSystem/Articles/WhereToPutFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001411-BAJHCHJI).

Comment: i just noticed, that i cannot save at all... iam saving using std -> std::ofstream file; file.open("~/Documents/menustate.sav", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary); ERROR_IF_ARG(!file.is_open(), "couldnt open file for saving at '%s'", fpath.c_str(), return);

Comment: `ofstream::open` has return type `void` so you cannot check for the UNIX `open` return value. You need to rely on the error state of the stream object, which is platform agnostic.

Comment: std::ofstream won't understand ~